# TFS 2015 is missing the "Deploy Azure App Service" task

Tags: azure, tfs-2015, release-management, azure-deployment, build-definition

I'm using TFS 2015 (Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
**Version 14.102.25423.0**)

but, I could only see "**Azure Web App Deployment**" Task, but not the "**Deploy Azure App Service**" task. How do I get the App Service task in my TFS Build definition.

This is the task I see in my TFS-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGIS3.jpg)

This is the task I want-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a90U.jpg)

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I'm using Powershell to package the code to support the virtual directory deployment as in a single zip file containing two folders - corresponding to one each virtual directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Web App Deployment task has been deprecated. But in TFS 2015, it still using it and in TFS 2017 and VSTS, it has been updated to use the Azure App Service Deploy task.

So if you want to use Azure App Service Deploy task, you could upload this task using **tfx command** to manually. The source files of the Azure App Service Deploy task is on the [Github site](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment). You could clone down the repository first.

**tfx command to upload a build task:**

http://donovanbrown.com/post/how-do-i-upload-a-custom-task-for-build

https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli

Comment: Hi, I cloned the respository. What in the world do I do with it? Do I only need to upload the AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4 task as described in the blog? Or do I need to build anything? How does Fiddler know what user to authenticate against? Is it the current AD user? I don't have permissions to upload it, so I need to ask a co-worker. I assume I have to run this all on his machine?